# Python How to find a keyword inside a column of data table after transforming the field texts into lower cases?

Tags: python, data-science

I need to find if a keyword in a field of an excel.

The first thing I want to do is transform this field into lowercase:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name = 1)
```

So I used the following:

```
data['Notes']=(map(str.upper, data['Notes']))
```

Where `Notes` is the field I want to use. But the function is returning something like this for each cell:

> 

I tried it using `list()`:

```
data['Notes']=list(map(str.upper, data['Notes']))
```

But I received an error:

> descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'map'

For the search, I made the following:

```
keywords = ['reception', 'warehouse', 'under construction', 'construction']
data['new field'] = ''
for note in data['Notes']:
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in note:
            data['new field'] = True
        else:
            data['new field'] = False
```

But the `new_field` is always contains `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to accomplish this is to utilize pandas' built in `str.contains` method:

```py
keywords = ['reception', 'warehouse', 'under construction', 'construction']
# make a regular expression of the keywords
kw_re = "|".join(keywords)

# Will return true is there is a match
data['New Field'] = data['Notes'].str.contains(kw_re, regex=True)
```

See full documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

Comment: It worked. But we transformed the `keyword` list into a regular expression in this case?

Comment: You want to test for many keywords @alim1990 – this is accomplished through the following regex format: `word_1|word_2` --> a dynamic solution to this is to apply the `|` separator through python's `.join` method operating on a list of keywords

Answer (score 2):

If you want to lowercase a column in pandas dataframe. It should be:

```
data['Notes'] = data['Notes'].str.lower()
# NOT THIS: data['Notes']=(map(str.upper, data['Notes']))
```

Now you can try looping over it and check:

```
keywords = ['reception', 'warehouse', 'under construction', 'construction']
data['new field'] = ''
for note in data['Notes']:
    if note in keywords:
        data['new field'] = True
    else:
        data['new field'] = False
```

Comment: still returning all fields `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [df["column"].str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
df["Notes"] = df["Notes"].str.lower()

# Separate your keywords with a |, like you would with commas in an array
#                                          [key, words] 
df["New Value"] = df["Notes"].str.contains("key|words")
```

Comment: all fields returned still as `False`.

Comment: Thank you, @alim1990. I've edited my answer to align with the Pandas documentation. Hope that helps!